# Why isn't my variable in a list behaving the way I expect it to?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to make a simple animation in Python using pygame where a block moves across the screen. I'm including (what I think are) the relevant parts of the code.

```
x, y = 1, 1

while True:

    rwidth, rheight = 10, 10
    left, top = x - (rwidth / 2), y - (rheight / 2)

    myRect = left, top, rwidth, rheight
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, white, myRect)

    position = [x, y]
    velocity = [5, 5]

    position[0] += velocity[0]
```

What's happening is the block appears where it is supposed to, but it doesn't move. However, if I replace `position[0] += velocity[0]` with `x += velocity[0]`, it does exactly what I want. From what I understand,`position[0]` and `x` should mean exactly the same thing. Why isn't this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of the fact that you are using the values `x` and `y` for drawing the block and not `position[0]` or `position[1]`. When you are updating the `position` values, the variables `x` and `y` remain same (see your code). So, for the time being `position` doesn't serve any purpose in your program except that it groups x and y values.

Answer (score 2):

They don't mean exactly the same thing at all times.  When you do `position = [x, y]`, you set position equal to a list the values `x` and `y` have *at that moment*.  `position` does not "auto-update" its value later when `x` changes (or vice versa).  If you change `position[0]`, you need to also change `x` yourself (and vice versa), or the two will go out of sync.

Answer (score 2):

The issue you're having is because integers in Python are immutable. Unlike some other objects (e.g. lists) that can be changed in-place with operators like `+=`, an `int` instance can never be changed from its current value. When you do something like `x += 1` (where `x` is an `int`), you really get `x = x + 1`, which creates a new integer object with the result of the sum, then rebinds `x` to the new value.

In your code, when you do `position = [x, y]`, you make a list with references to two integers that are also bound to the variables `x` and `y`. However, when you do `position[0] += velocity[0]`, the identity between `x` and `position[0]` breaks down. When dealing with immutable objects, that statement is equivalent to `position[0] = position[0] + velocity[0]`, which creates a new value and stores it in the list, replacing `x`. The name `x` remains bound to the previous value, which is unchanged.